# tortoise svn 1.7 - date format of $Date $

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are using different PCs (some of them windows xp, some of them windows 7). With tortoise and the tags I've detected some problem resulting in problems comparing complete trees 1:1.

One system is replacing the date tag to:

```
$Date: 2015-02-27 17:14:05 +01000 (Fr, 27 Feb 2015) $
```

Another system gives on the same source code status

```
$Date: 2015-02-27 17:14:05 +01000 (Fr, 27. Feb 2015) $
```

By performing a compare then every file is marked as different, because after the day (number) there is a point or no point.

It seems that all xp installations are working without points, the win 7 ones with points. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Since keyword expansion is a [client-side operation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html), I'd think your TSVN clients are different versions.  I don't see anything incriminating in the [SVN function, `svn_time_to_human_cstring`, that performs the expansion](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_subr/), so maybe it's a change in the versions of [`apr_strftime`](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__time.html#ga3f5e1aa45e735f3bcf8c13fb718c214f) that SVN uses?

Comment: Right, the versions of tortoise are different: Windows 7 TortoiseSVN 1.7.6.22632 (64 bit), Windows XP TortoiseSVN 1.6.6.17493 (32 bit). Is there a way to influence the system by different environment-variables? (Please forgive my frequent editing - every time I hit Return (to go to a new line) stackoverflow-site submits the text. BTW: How to introduce Returns in comments?)

Comment: I'm not in a position to confirm that I see the same behavior, but using 1.8.8 on Win7 does not produce the period that you see. It's possible there's a bug in that version of TSVN that isn't reported.  I'd try playing around with different (preferably more recent) versions of TSVN to see where that bug may have been introduced.

Comment: After updating the XP installation to tortoise 1.7.6 (32 bit), the difference still is there.

Comment: Windows XP (32 bit) without point, windows 7 (64 bit) with point.

Comment: Windows XP: Java 1.6.0.29, Windows 7: Java 1.7.0.51

Answer (score 0):

I experience exactly the same issue with the dot in the $Date-tag using Win7 and TortoiseSVN 1.9.2 (will be updated now to the latest and greatest; 1.9.5).
Did anyone discover the reason and can provide a solution?

Problem is: all of those files will show up as "changed" with the ongoing behaviour which clutters view on the real changeset of commits.
(One way to fix this, would be to write a script and run it everytime before/after commit.. But there has to be a way to influence the formatting of that string.)

Comment: Hey, this does not answer the question posed originally be OP. Consider asking your own question and link back to this question for reference if you are unable to find a question and answer that provides a solution through search.